# phonegap JQUERY.GET() doesnt work on blackberry app

Tags: jquery, cordova, blackberry

I'm developing PhoneGap to get XML data from a remote site. the code works on ripple simulator but not work on blackberry app

Any idea how to solve my problem?

### here 's the code

```
jquery.get(RSS, {}, function(res, code) {
entries = [];
var xml = $(res);
var items = xml.find("artikel");
jquery.each(items, function(i, v) {
entry = { 

 title:$(v).find("title").text(),
 subtitle:$(v).find("subtitle").text()

    };
        entries.push(entry);
});
```

Comment: You 've written `jquery`. Is it a typo? `jQuery` the correct var name, if included. It may not your only problem.

Comment: it suppose to be $  , well just for info  im using bb os 7 &  i have try the code on  android and it's work fine

Comment: Hello any body home ?